# how to print firebase image in dompdf laravel?

Tags: laravel, firebase, dompdf

```
/*
<img src="{{$users['image']}}" />
*/
```

Where `$users['image']` is the field of table where I store the firebase image URL.

Answer (score 0):

Access it like so if an user is logged in:

```
<img src="{{Auth::user()->image}}" />
```

Comment: No effect of this